# IonicPopup changes background color when called

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have created an ionic pop up with the following code as shown:

```
$ionicPopup.alert({
                          title: title,
                          content: 'Username or password is incorrect!'
                        });
```

When the above popup is called, it changes the application background color to a different color as shown in the picture below: [image]
If I click on the okay button, it returns to the application with normal  background color. Any idea could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change background color of ionic popup and its backdrop.

CSS:

```
 .popup-container {
       background-color: transparent;
    }
    .backdrop{
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
```

Try this.

Comment: I added this and it worked perfectly okay .popup-container
{

    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

}